# NiFi: Merge an Attribute into the Flow-file's JSON Content (without overwriting the entire flowfile)

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a flow that creates some new attributes / content. I want to take an attribute from the flow files, and add it into the JSON content of the file.

I can use `AttributesToJSON`, but that just overwrites the file content.

A sample of my flow is here:

[image]

The `UpdateAttribute` adds current time to the attribute list, and then the `AttributestoJSON` adds an attribute to the actual JSON, but it also **overwrites** the entire flow file content. I've tried to remedy this with `MergeRecord`, but I can't the two files to merge back together (using `CurrentTime` as a Correlation Attribute Name).

Is there a better to go about this? The `MergeRecord` just comes up with an error. (Also not sure how to configure the RecordReader/Writer, because I want to keep everything in JSON).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use UpdateRecord and add a property where the name is the field you want to update like "/currentTime" and the value is the expression language reference to the attribute like ${currentTime}, assuming you set currentTime in UpdateAttribute.

Comment: So I was really reaching towards complexity for no reason... I'm dumb. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Question: I want to keep it JSON, so for the reader/writers, what's the best method? JSONTree or Path?

Comment: JsonTreeReader, you would only use JsonPathReader if you want to specify specific paths from the json, the tree reader just reads everything

Comment: is there a way to write into a nested object within the target json. Something like /currentTime/bar